# JavaRX to join two continuously updated states

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have 2 continuously updated states:

- *Product State* which contains list of products (Id, Name, Currency of
  cell, Price in currency of cell).
- *Currency Rates State* which contains current currency rates (Currency,
  Rate in USD).

Both these states are represented by two correspondent live streams. To be precise, *state* in this context is just a virtual view which contains last versions of data received from streams. And I need to provide live stream of the following data: Product Id, Product Name, Price in USD.

It means that I need something like `left join` but for streaming data.

I've tried to use **RxJava** [`groupJoin`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/join.html) for this purpose, but I got two problems:

1. I can't ask `groupJoin` to provide only last version of data for each
   stream (last currency rate to join with product or last product
   version to merge with rates).
2. I can't use any index like HashMap to improve joining (for instance
   select rate by currency as a key), I can only iterate over all data
   (like full scan).

How can I solve these problems? Is **RxJava** applicable for my purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>`

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals
>   reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
>   holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as putAll and
>   clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only
>   some entries. Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements
>   reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the
>   creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be
>   used by only one thread at a time

Quoted from [Documentaiton of ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)
I think is the best choice for what you want and need.

Comment: Yes, `ConcurrentHashMap` is a solution of course, but does *RxJava* support this type of join by some special feature? Or is it aligned with reactive programming approach at least?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [CombineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) operator. It works like a `zip` operation, but emits a new item every time **any** of the sources observables emits an item.

With this operator you will always get the latest `ProductState` and `CurrencyRate`.

You could do something like this (Kotlin syntax):

```
Observable.combineLatest(productStream, currencyStream) { product, currency ->
    NewView(product.id, product.name, product.price * currency.rate)
}
```